# how to set Robotium test priority?

Tags: android, android-studio, automated-tests, robotium

I want to set test cases in queue. Now they runs by alphabetic queue in Run Congiguration: Android Tests, but how to set Robotium test priority?

For example I want to run at first `testSecond`, and only then `testFirst`, how to configure that?

```
public void setUp() throws Exception {
       super.setUp();
       solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation());
       getActivity();
     }

     @Override
     public void tearDown() throws Exception {
       solo.finishOpenedActivities();
       super.tearDown();
     }

     public void testFirst() {}

     public void testSecond() {}
```

Comment: That's not a response, but it would be better if your tests was completely independants...

Comment: @Médéric should I create differents classes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765129/how-to-run-robotium-tests-in-a-specific-order

Answer (score 0):

The priority is based on the characters. In other words, it runs from A to Z.